# python importing from subfolders

Tags: python, import

When I import a subdirectory and assign it a variable name, why am I then unable to import modules from this subdirectory via the variable name?

Eg my directory structure is:

```
root\
    f1\
        f2\
            m1.py
```

when I do the following, everything is fine:

```
from f1.f2 import m1
```

But when I do the following, python interprets the from selection as a module and throws an error:

```
import f1.f2 as f

from f import m1

Error msg: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f'
```

Why is f interpreted as a module and not the subdirectory f2 contained in f1?

Comment: You did not create an `__init__.py` in your packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python grammar doesn't allow expressions after `from`:

```
import f1.f2 as f
from f import m1
```

`f` in the second line is a variable expression, and the Python grammar (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) thinks it has found a `NAME`, which is then fed to the import machinery to find a module named `f`:

```
Error msg: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f'
```

You could do

```
import f1.f2 as f
m1 = f.m1
```

instead...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **init**.py module in your package. Python recognizes such folders as packages.

Create an **init**.py file in the root folder, the f1 folder, and the f2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `from` or `import`, Python is looking for a module with the name that you are passing. You have to first import from the actual module name and then use your variables.

*Example:*

```py
>>> import random as ran
>>> from ran import *      ## we cannot import from the variable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ran'
>>> ran.randint(1, 10)     ## but we now can use our variable 
8
>>>
```

Comment: that's interesting, i thought variables were replaced by what they referenced by python?

Comment: I think the reason variables are not allowed here is to avoid conflicts between variable and module names. e.g., I can import `random`, but I can also have a variable by the same name without conflict.